# Instancing an Interface in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to represent the following situation in a UML Class Diagram.

1. We have a class named Selection where the user select how will the
   next screen be.
2. The selection class has a property screen: Screen, where screen is an interface.
3. There are multiple implementations of the interface screen. ex. SimpleScreen, SuperScreen, etc.
4. The screen property in selection class should be able to contain an instance of any implementation of screen depending on user choice.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do this in OO?
2. How would the Class Diagram representation look like for this case?

Right now I have a diagram like this: http://yuml.me/1dcb2f2f

If you want to modify the diagram I used yuml.me this is the link http://yuml.me/edit/1dcb2f2f

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do it in OO. The correct UML notation is:

http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/nextScreen.jpg

Comment: Great, this is what I wanted. So is it possible in a OO language such as Java or C++ to do `Screen userSelection = new SuperScreen();` for example? Thx

Comment: Yes. Although, if I remember well, in C++ you don't have interfaces so, you will use abstract classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to act upon an abstract 'screen' polymorphically the implementations would have to adhere to a common interface or inherit from a common base class.

I'm not sure of the proper way to UML this, I think you've got the diagram about right.

Answer (score 0):

Get acquainted with **design patterns**.

Use **factory method** (produce instance based on the user choice) +
**singleton** (makes factory easily accessible and ensures that only one factory exists) for producing instance of needed class +
**object composition** with **bridge pattern**(allows to decouple interface from implementation and allows to switch implementation in a run-time/)